# Finding a way for using and async to be friends

Tags: c#, asynchronous, ado.net, task

Most people have discovered using and async are not good friends because often the one execution path disposes of the connection while another is still trying to use it.

So I came up with...

```
static async public Task<TResult> AsyncUsingConnection<TResult>(string connectionString,Func<SqlConnection, Task<TResult>> functiod) 
{
    TResult result;
    SqlConnection connection = null;
    try
    {
        connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        connection.Open();
        var resultTask = functiod(connection);
        
        resultTask.ContinueWith(t => { 
            connection?.Dispose();
            connection = null;
        });
        return await resultTask;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        connection?.Dispose();
        connection = null;
        throw;
    }
}
```

which allow me to write..

```
AsyncUsingConnection("myconnectionString", async (connection)=> {

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from foo");
    var reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();
    while (await reader.ReadAsync()) {
        ....    
    }
    reader.Close();
);
```

Let's ignore the fact the in reality I also need to dispose the `DataReader` ( just for clarities sake we'll only focus on one `IDisposable`),

Firstly my code analysis engine wants to destroy the readability by wanting to liberally sprinkle `ConfigureAwaits(false)` everywhere.

But it also keeps suggesting I await the `ContinueWith` ; now my thinking is that I create the `resultTask` as the result of the function, I then attach a `ContinueWith` to dispose the connection when `resultTask` completes, and only then do I await `resultTask` and return the value ( while the `ContinueWith` tidies up);

Have I done this right ? or is there anything I could do better/ more robustly.

Comment: Replace `try .. catch` with `using` block

Comment: `one execution path disposes of the connection while another is still trying to use it.` - this really doesn't have anything to do with `async`, though. Code should dispose of instances it owns, and not dispose of other instances. Whether it's async or sync is immaterial.

Comment: @StephenCleary - "one execution path disposes of the connection while another is still trying to use it." - this really doesn't have anything to do with async


really I thought the whole idea as async was moving work to 'the background'

Comment: @BarryWimlett: Yes, but `await` will asynchronously wait. So if you're using *both* `async` and `await` in the natural way, then a normal `using` would work just the same as for synchronous code.

Answer (score 3):

To wrap sql connection boiler plate into the method

```
public static async Task<TResult> Execute(
    string connectionString, 
    Func<SqlConnection, Task<TResult>> execute
)
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        await connection.OpenAsync();
        return await execute(connection);
    }
}
```

`Using` will dispose connection properly in all possible scenarios (success or error)

`return await` is a key in this method, because it will return result only after `execute` method is complete.